# Python3, SQLite3 double escaped backslash in tuples

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples, escaping

i am using Python3 and SQLite3 within Windows.
when i create a query like

```
qfilename = r'C:\autoexec.bat'

con = sqlite3.connect("database.db3")
cur = con.cursor()
data = cur.execute("SELECT sha512 FROM filetable WHERE filename = ?", (qfilename,))
```

it has no results, because in a tuple qfilename gets some extra baskslashes ('')

How can i suppress this behavior?

```
test = "hello world\\python"
print(test)      # :-) everything fine: hello world\python
print((test,))   # unexpected behavior: hello world\\python
```

thank for your help...

Comment: The 'extra' backslash is because when you print a container like a list or a tuple, python prints the _repr_ of the contained items - you'll see if you do `print(repr(test))`.  If I run an equivalent query I retrieve the expected value.  Can you provide an [mre]?